is this a bug on ubuntu 22.04 LTS?
PROBLEM:
when i remove all users from the login screen  by editing /var/lib/AccountsService/users
and changing all users to systemaccount=true and restart my computer , after this ubuntu does not boot until i add a user to the login screen by opening root shell prompt in the recovery menu and opening the config file using nano editor and adding a user back to the login screen.

No, this is not a bug. It is how it works. Make sure to have at least one user on the system.
